# Blogger profile changes to nameless profile when I try to follow blogs

Tags: google-account, blogger

I have a blogger profile (seen in `www.planetzella.blogspot.com` - Zella). I am NOT using Google+ (and I don't want to start using it either) and do not have a Google+ profile, just a Gmail account which obviously has the same log-in information as my blog.

If I try to start following new blogs by joining the site, my profile in others' blogs appears without a photograph and with no name - previously Blogger connected this to my Blogger profile correctly. If I click on my "profile" which appears on the blog/site I've started to follow, it shows no user name, just the blogs that I follow. However, if I post a comment on the blog, my comments DO come up connected to my Blogger profile (Zella).

Is the problem my lack of Google+ i.e. when someone's blog has the option to "join this site", does that refer to Google+?

And since I do not have a Google+ profile, my Gmail user name comes up without connection to my own blog?

Comment: The blog `www.planetzella.blogspot.com` is not public. It's not clear if this had been this way since the question was asked, on the other hand, the question had been bumped 40 times, the OP have not edited the question since the question was posted.